# Вращение объекта

Tags: blender

Столкнулся с такой проблемкой, стрелка повернута под углом, получается, что для её вращения нужно задействовать одновременно две оси, собственно вопрос - можно ли задать объекту вращение по одной оси, чтобы при этом он корректно вращался и не заходил за полигон?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Легче всего такие объекты сразу делать правильно. Т.е. создать стрелку параллельно одной из осей координат, а затем уже в Объектном режиме, повернуть ее в нужном направлении. Привязка с поворотом относительно поверхности сделает задачу простой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]